# Jquery horizontal scroll next item button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scroll

I'm working on horizontal onepage web page, I added a menu which works and goes to each content. But, on this webpage, I added next and previous button, but when I'm clicking on the next button it doesn't go to the next slide.
Here is my fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/jarod51/x66hA/3/

the script that  I wrote for the next button :

```
$(function() {
    $('#next').bind('click',function(event){
         event.preventDefault();
        var $anchor = $(this);

$("html, body").stop().animate({
                       scrollLeft: $($anchor).offset().left

                   }, 1000);
               });  
 });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
$('#next').bind('click',function(event){
     event.preventDefault();
    var $anchor = $(this);
```

What is $(this) exactly? It's the #next. Then you apply

```
$($anchor).offset().left
```

offset left based on #next. This will not work, you have to apply it on the divs you want to show.

Try to fix it accordingly. To give you an idea :

http://jsfiddle.net/x66hA/7/

This of course will work only for #newsletter, but you should get the error and work from there.

Comment: Hi Andrew, thanks for your help. I actually wanted, each time that you click on the next button it goes to the next slide. So, as I wrote my script, it works only for one anchor. Is it possible to have a next button which shows next slide by slide each time when you click on ?

Comment: In your initial script, your "next" button doesn't really work for me, even for the next slide. Anyhow, how is something like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/x66hA/8/

Comment: Great Andrew ! It works well. That I was looking for. I tried to adapt your script for the prev button, but it doesn't work.

Comment: $(function() {
    $('#prev').bind('click',function(event){
         event.preventDefault();
        var lis = $("li");
        var currentLi = $(lis[i]);
        i += 1 % lis.length;      
        var $anchor = currentLi.children('a').attr('href');        
        console.log($anchor);  
        
$("html, body").stop().animate({
                 scrollRight: $($anchor).offset().right
        
             }, 1000);
         });
    
 });

Comment: jsfiddle your attempt and I'll give it a look

Comment: Here it is: http://jsfiddle.net/x66hA/11/

PLEASE NOTE: This is a MESS. It's a correction over a correction. I just wanted to point out your mistake and ended up bug-fixing code that needs refactoring.

Comment: Thx so much Andrew for your help. I understood well your code. On the prev button needed to decrement the i by i=i-1. I didn't think of it. I'm so happy for your help.

Comment: flag the question as answered if that's the case, please :) (The V sign near my original answer)